# Navigation menu list in Grav

Tags: grav

I am new to Grav and I am trying to get the basics.
If I want the following page structure:

```
root
|_______ set1 
|           |___ page_10
|           |___ page_11
|           |___ page_12
|
|_______ set2
|           |___ page_20
|           |___ page_21
...
```

How can I make *set1* display a regular navigation menu with links to each inner page?

Something like:

```
- Page 10
- Page 11
- Page 12
```

Where each entry is an html link to each page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with twig with something like this:

```
{% for childpage in page.header.children %}
<a href="{{childpage.url}}">{{ childpage.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This iterate through all the children of your page, and display a link and the page title.